# What is the current best validation framework for asp.net apps?

Tags: validation, frameworks, design-by-contract

To make sure its a DRY approach all validation logic should of course go in the business logic (model).

- How are validation messages presented to views, should be able to localize error messages
- Can you generate javascript from the validation framework. Compatibility with JQuery would be perfect
- Is the framework compatible with a DbC approach?

Edit:
I think this is the nicest one until now, Castle validator + live validation
http://blog.codeville.net/2008/04/30/model-based-client-side-validation-for-aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

[Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309509.aspx)

from Microsoft is one alternative but I have no experience with it